# secure query included inaccessible field

Tags: soql, permissions, profile, exception, field-level-security

I have a test method which I am trying to run from a particular profile. I am trying to access an object called Interaction and that profile has real all record permission.

When I am running the first query it is working fine and returning results.

```
system.debug([SELECT Id FROM Interaction]);
```

This one fails with an error message secure query included inaccessible field.

```
system.debug([SELECT Id FROM Interaction WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED]);
```

Comment: Your user doesn't have access to the object being queried. Make sure the user's license type allows access, and that the user has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I checked that profile and it has Read all permission checked for the Interaction object.

Comment: Did the user have permission to use the Financial Service Cloud? Again, this error is telling you that the user doesn't have access.

Comment: No. How can I give this permission to the user in the test context?